# Need help in this url htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2

I uploaded the yii2 basic in x10hosting site. it works fine but,the url is not good to look.here is the sample url

`http://myappdomain.x10host.com/home/myfolderapp/public_html/site/contact`

I used this htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

how can I remove this part

`home/myfolderapp/public_html`

so that it would look like this

`http://myappdomain.x10host.com/site/contact`

Comment: update your webroot to `home/myfolderapp/public_html`

Comment: if you insist using htaccess solution you can try link that given by chris. or using yii configuration http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if [this solution helps](http://www.zimplicit.se/en/knowledge/how-host-primary-domain-subfolder-using-htaccess).

Comment: Link only answers are not welcomed on SO. Please add essential part of it to answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?

```
RewriteEngine on
# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?myappdomain.x10host.com$
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/myfolderapp/public_html/
# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/myfolderapp/public_html/$1
# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?myappdomain.x10host.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ home/myfolderapp/public_html/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteBase /
```

I installed Grav and had this issue too but now it's working. http://kazeflame.elementfx.com/home